# Can i use node as webserver for html app?

Tags: node.js

I'm sorry to ask such a simple question. I've been sent files by someone, an index.html file which pulls in a js file within `script` tags. I have to start a webserver to get through authentication and view the files (am in dev).

In my CLI i have navigated to the directory containing index.html. I have checked with `node -v` that I have it installed globally (yes, v 8.6). I've run the simple command `node` and checked my browser at http://localhost:3000 and a few other ports but get no joy. I've also tried `node index.html` but CLI throws an error.

How do i start the webserver? All the examples online tell me to build a .js file, but this is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its very easy to start a server using node js**

Create a `server.js` file,

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
  });
}).listen(3000);
```

Run `node server.js`

[**Here is a reference**](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/shownodejs.asp?filename=demo_readfile)

This will even solve your backslash issue by this

Comment: Glad to help you. :-)

Answer (score 3):

**Steps to set up a node web server**

1. Create the route folder from your local machine.
2. Go to the command prompt from the project root path.
3. Install express using the command **npm install express**
4. Create **server.js** file
5. create the folder **wwww** and create the **Index.html** inside it.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

app.listen('3000');
console.log('working on 3000');
```

**Index.html**

```
<!doctype html
<html> 
<head> 
<title> my local server </title> 
</head>
<body>
<h1> server working </h1>
<p> just put your html,css, js files here and it work on your own local nodejs server </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Go to the project root path and take the command prompt, then start the server by running the command **node server.js**

Then go to the browser and run the url **localhost:3000**.

Now you can see the html page will render on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

A very simple example of how to do this would be to create file, let's call it `app.js` and put this in it:

```
const http = require('http'),   // to listen to http requests
      fs = require('fs');       // to read from the filesystem

const app = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    // status should be 'ok'
    res.writeHead(200); 

    // read index.html from the filesystem, 
    // and return in the body of the response
    res.end(fs.readFileSync("index.html")); 
});

app.listen(3000); // listen on 3000
```

Now, run `node app.js`

Browse to `http://localhost:3000`

There's loads of other npm packages that will help you out do this, but this is the simplest 'pure node' example to literally read index.html and serve it back as the response.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I need an extra backslash before the index.html. Currently CLI throws error looking for folderNameindex.html. I've tried various forward and backward slashes within the double quotes, plus os.tmpdir(). Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to build a backend but just an http server.
I would propose to use an npm package that do just what you need:

Open a console

`npm install http-server -g`

Go to your "index.html" folder (in the console) then type:

`http-server`

Then reach your content in your browser at this address:

`http://localhost:8080`

Documentation here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Thank you for this. Currently the download keeps timing out due to connectivity issues. I don't think I'm behind a proxy as I've used npm install successfully before. If you know about this subject i'd be grateful