# Javascript insert backslash: __dirname + "index.html"

Tags: javascript

in the question below, someone has given me the following code:

```
res.end(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "index.html"));
```

However this is creating a filename of folderNameindex.html, i.e. there needs to be a backslash before index.html. From googling, the solution should be two x \ within the double quotes, resulting in "\index.html". I've tried this and many other variations, single, double, treble, forward slashes, regex escaping. In every case, my CLI tells me it cannot find file folderNameindex.html.

This is probably simple. Grateful for any help.

[Can i use node as webserver for html app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750738/can-i-use-node-as-webserver-for-html-app)

EDIT:

My new code:

```
const http = require('http'),   // to listen to http requests
      path = require('path'),
      fullPath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
      fs = require('fs');       // to read from the filesystem

const app = http.createServer((req,res) => {
    // status should be 'ok'
    res.writeHead(200);

    // read index.html from the filesystem,
    // and return in the body of the response

    res.end(fs.readFileSync(fullPath)); });

app.listen(3000); // listen on 3000
```

I still get the same error - my command line tells me it can't find folderNameindex.html

Comment: Use `path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')`.

Comment: You must use slash instead of backslash. And just one slash.

Answer (score 0):

You should use path.join, for example;

```
const path = require('path')
const fullPath = path.join(__dirname, 'index.html')
```

Additionally, there are many other functions that will help you working with paths in a portable way, make sure to read all the docs for the [path](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) and [file system](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) module.

Comment: Thank you, but this still hasn't worked. I've edited my question with the new code.

Comment: @emma you should replace the `res.end` line with `res.sendFile(fullPath)` (or `res.download(fullPath)`), have a look at the docs; http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download